Virtualbox Ubuntu (Guest) shared VPN with VSCode on Windows (Host)
I have a Windows host machine where I can connect two Ethernet adapters. Currently I am using one for the host and one for the guest (Ubuntu) in Virtualbox. On the guest I have a Fortinet VPN client working without any issues (through a Bridge Adapter mode), and on the host an OpenVPN client connection that also works.
Both VPNs are working independently on separate Network cards. But now I would like to ssh from the host machine (Windows) to the guest (Ubuntu) VPN network.
Is there a way to route ssh traffic from Windows host machine to the guest Linux VPN?

The easiest method is to use OpenSSH's "jump host" feature:
ssh -J virtualbox_address real_address

If you define the jump host through the ssh_config file (same location on both Windows and Linux), it will automatically work with VSCode, Git, and other software that runs ssh internally.

~/.ssh/config ($env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\config)
Host real_address
    ProxyJump virtualbox_address

While you're at it, you can also use the same ssh_config file to define the default SSH username and other parameters if you want.

~/.ssh/config (%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config)
Host webserver
    ProxyJump vbox
    HostName myserv123.blah.example.com
    Port 22222
    User root

Host vbox
    # "NAT network" port forwarding
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    Port 23456

…then ssh webserver will automatically use the correct hostname and all.
Windows doesn't really have flexible "policy routing" to route only SSH traffic at system level (or maybe it does via WFP, but none of that is easily accessible), and at the same time I kind of expect the various 'corporate' VPN clients themselves to be using WFP to prevent traffic from going sideways, so if you can configure OpenSSH itself to do the proxying, that'll be by far the easiest option as far as I know.

Hi @grawity,
many thanks for your precious input. The jump host might be a good idea indeed.
My corporate just changed the vpn from openvpn to other VPN type(I think big-ip)...so more research and try outs...I really would like to have a solution that does not affect my work setup everytime any top manager decides to change the color of vpn flavours :-)

Quick question: with the ssh jump host method I would still require 2 networks in the Virtual Machine guest right? One in Bridge mode (for internet access and VPN) and one Host -only ? or NAT? To make the ssh jump host from windows through Linux guest to my vpn-fortinet network.
Many thanks once again.

Generally I'd say no, one network is enough (either NAT or bridge will be able to provide both VM->Internet access and host->VM access) since this method only needs a plain TCP connection, no fancy routing – but it depends on the VPN software really, as some "corporate" VPN apps set up really annoying filters that prevent LAN access while the VPN is active.
